# Is such a continuous function always holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume $\Omega$ is connected. Suppose we have two functions $f,g:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f$ is continuous and $g$ is holomorphic.  Suppose we know that $|f|=|g|$ on $\Omega$.  Is it necessarily true that $f$ or $\overline{f}$ must be holomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false, let $\Omega=\mathbb{C}$, $f:z\mapsto\exp(\textrm{Re}(z))$ and $g:z\mapsto\exp(z)$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider any $\Omega$, a non constant $g$ and $f=\lvert g\rvert$. Non-constant holomorphic functions are open maps, so:

1. they have non-constant modulus
2. they are never real-valued

Therefore, neither $f$ nor $\overline f=f$ are holomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

This implies that $f=ge^{ih(z)}$, take $h$ any continuous function real valued, $f$ is not always holomorphic. For example $g(z)=z$ and $h(z)=|z|$.